# Event handlers not triggering when rendering reactjs components from nodejs server using express-react-views module

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using express-react-views package to render react components in serverside(NodeJs).

I have created my react component. There is a button with an `onClick` event. I have tried to debug the issue but the event is not triggering. How should I fix this issue?

My `server.js` file:

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const router = express.Router();
const cors = require("cors");
const logger = require("morgan");
const { config } = require("./config/config");
const app = express();
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:5000",
    credentials: true
  })
);
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/views"));
app.set("view engine", "jsx");
app.engine("jsx", require("express-react-views").createEngine());

router.get("/test", (req, res) => {
  res.render("test");
});
app.use("/", router);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log(`App Started on PORT ${process.env.PORT || 5000}`);
});
```

My `test.jsx` file:

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: "Initial data..."
    };
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
  }
  updateState() {
    this.setState({ data: "Data updated..." });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.updateState}>CLICK</button>
        <h4>{this.state.data}</h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

In `test.jsx` file, the `onClick` event is not firing. I'm stuck with this issue. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As evident from the docs -

> This is an Express view engine which renders React components on
>   server. It renders static markup and does not support mounting those
>   views on the client.

The library is just meant to render static markup and not support any client side mounting for isomorphic apps.

So basically you're not sending any js to the client ( with React and ReactDOM ) to mount the rendered component on the client and make your eventHandlers work.

To solve this, you might want to have a build pipeline ( using webpack, rollup, babel, etc) to bundle up your js files and serve them over a static server. Also for server rendering have a look at -> [ReactDomServer](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you show an example of how can I do this? Do you have any example to work the above requirement? That is nodejs + express-react-view + webpack?

Comment: I don't have an example for you. But you can start with reading webpack ( or any bundler in that case) docs to setup binding in your project.