# React onClick function on button is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a simple webpage using React and Express. The page consists of a button and a number which should get incremented on clicking the button. I have used the number state to keep track of the value to be displayed and passed the component to my ejs file. Here are the codes for reference.

The react component  **test.jsx**

```
import React from "react"

export default function Test(){
    const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(0);

    function add(){
        console.log(number)
        setNumber(number => number+1)
    }
    
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={add}>Click Me</button>
            <p>{number}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I'm then passing this component to my ejs file through  my router file

**test.js**

```
import React from "react"
import express from "express"
import {renderToString} from "react-dom/server.js"
import Test from "./test.jsx"

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
    const reactComp = renderToString(<Test/>);
    res.render("./test", {reactApp: reactComp});
})

module.exports = router;
```

**test.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="body"> <%- reactApp %> </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the page gets rendered but the button does not seem to be working. The add function never gets called since there are no logs. Has it got something to do with the fact that I'm rendering through an ejs file? How do I make this work?

Comment: You can take a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56609487/event-handlers-not-triggering-when-rendering-reactjs-components-from-nodejs-serv).

Comment: "*The ReactDOMServer object enables you to render components to static markup*"; events and DOM specific stuff (basically any interactivity) gets filtered out. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference links! I managed to do it by using hydrate and configuring my webpack to create a bundle.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you just use axios ? or build a client to make the requests